# android slow connection force close

Tags: android

I don't know why but my app is being force closed and it has slow connection.
How to handle such situation I check internet connection before posting data

```
11-03 15:14:57.836: W/dalvikvm(13548): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41636d40)
11-03 15:14:57.839: E/AndroidRuntime(13548): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 15:14:57.839: E/AndroidRuntime(13548): Process: com.androidhive.pushnotifications, PID: 13548
11-03 15:14:57.839: E/AndroidRuntime(13548): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=6
11-03 15:14:57.839: E/AndroidRuntime(13548):    at com.androidhive.pushnotifications.MessageActivity$sendMessageN.onPostExecute(MessageActivity.java:1798)
11-03 15:14:57.839: E/AndroidRuntime(13548):    at com.androidhive.pushnotifications.MessageActivity$sendMessageN.onPostExecute(MessageActivity.java:1)
11-03 15:14:57.839: E/AndroidRuntime(13548):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
11-03 15:14:57.839: E/AndroidRuntime(13548):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
11-03 15:14:57.839: E/AndroidRuntime(13548):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
11-03 15:14:57.839: E/AndroidRuntime(13548):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-03 15:14:57.839: E/AndroidRuntime(13548):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-03 15:14:57.839: E/AndroidRuntime(13548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
11-03 15:14:57.839: E/AndroidRuntime(13548):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 15:14:57.839: E/AndroidRuntime(13548):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-03 15:14:57.839: E/AndroidRuntime(13548):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-03 15:14:57.839: E/AndroidRuntime(13548):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-03 15:14:57.839: E/AndroidRuntime(13548):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

```java
class sendMessageN extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

     int success = 0;
     protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sender",myAcc));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reciever",filename));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message",mess));
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(send_text);
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        int some_reasonable_timeout = (int) (30 * DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, some_reasonable_timeout);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, some_reasonable_timeout);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
        try
        {
          request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
          StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
          if (status.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
          {
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            error = responseHandler.handleResponse(response);
            success = 1;
          }
          else
          {

          }
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
          // Do something else, if wanted.
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
          // Do something else, if wanted.
        }
        finally
        {
          client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
        return error; 
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result != null){
         if (success == 1) {
        //data send to server successfully  
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is in MessageActivity OutofBound error, Check this  com.androidhive.pushnotifications.MessageActivity$sendMessageN.onPostExecute(MessageActivity.java:1798)

Comment: first check net connection than post data (call webservice)

Comment: example to check net in here r not http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-detect-internet-connection-status/

Comment: Its not the slow connection issue, its IndexOutofBoubd issue, first check internet connection and then call your webservices and check your array and then use it.